# How to force a button inside a div not to inherit the parent CSS?

Tags: css

I have a div in which which   there is a form and a submit button; I ahve given the form the following CSS:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%, #fff), color-stop(90%, #f2f2f2));
```

this background is applied to my button CSS which a bootstrap button; how can I force it not to inherit from the parent?

ADDED:

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/fGY3Q/1/

The whole CSS:

```
width: 40%;
height: 40%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%, #fff), color-stop(90%, #f2f2f2));

box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;border: 2px solid #d6d6d6;
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your css selector ? And what is your html ? Do you only use -webkit- gradient ? No FF or IE ?

Comment: Could you give us a JSFiddle to work with? Perhaps an example of your Markup?

Comment: @Brewal Google-Chrome

Comment: Alsoe edited the full CSS

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/fGY3Q/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to the fact that you have 2 controls with the same id of upload. Your wrapping `div` and your `submit` button.

To fix it, simply remove the `id` and `name` attributes from the submit button.  You also had invalid `br` tags.  I fixed those too.

[***See working jsFiddle demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/4YQf6/)

*I'll leave you to clean up the markup and css to make the box and its controls line up and look all pretty. =D*

---

### HTML

```
<div id="upload">
    <form action='http://test' method='post' accept-charset='utf-8' class='form-horizontal' enctype='multipart/form-data' style='text-align:center;'>
        <br />
        <div class='control-group'>
            <input type='file' name='userfile' value='' id='userfile' class='btn btn-primary' required='true' style=' width:290px;' />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label for='name'>Name</label>
            <input type='text' name='associateName' value='' id='name' required='required' placeholder='Name' />
        </div>
        <div class='control-group'>
            <label for='dept'>Department Name</label>
            <input type='text' name='dept' value='' id='dept' required='required' placeholder='Department Name' />
            <br />
            <input id='startDateUpload' name='startDateUpload' value='" + $.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings) + "' type='hidden' />
            <input id='endDateUpload' name='endDateUpload' value='" + $.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings) + "' type='hidden' />
            <input id='seg' name='seg' value='0' type='hidden' />
            <input id='total' name='total' type='hidden' />
        </div>
        <input type='submit' value='Upload' class='con btn btn-primary' />
    </form>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#upload 
{
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%, #fff), color-stop(90%, #f2f2f2));
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    border: 2px solid #d6d6d6;
}
```

Comment: Did not work man! BTW it is a dynamic html; appeared by an AJAX CALL and HTML atribute

Comment: You would have to make sure that the css button background is being applied _after_ the parent's background is applied.

Comment: Sorry I'm not good at CSS; how can I make sure it gets applied after parrent? if you mean the order in my CSS file yes I applied CSS for my upload button after div CSS

Comment: What do you specifically not want? I looked at your fiddle and can't tell what you _do_ want vs what you _don't_ want.

Comment: I dont want to ahve shadow and background for my button

Comment: yea but please chekc my updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/fGY3Q/1/

Comment: I found your problem.  It's the classic case of 2 controls having the same id.  You can't do that.  Your div is upload and so is your button.

Comment: If you like please put it as an answe and I will accept is as solved!

Answer (score 0):

Either you just apply it to certain input types only, e.g. like this:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="email"], textarea {
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%, #fff), color-stop(90%, #f2f2f2));
}
```

Or if you apply it to all of them, you can remove it from the button input type by declaring this afterwards.

```
input[type="submit"] {
   background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code working in JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sHxDq/

It appears the background is not being inherited to the button, could you post some of your html markup?

Alternatively, you could make sure there is no background rule being applied to the button with something like this:

I would add some rule like this:

```
.button{
   background: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I see that your button and your div have the same ID. Not only is this the cause of the problem, but there should never be two elements with the same ID in a webpage. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp